# how to collect user message in DM in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to gather a user's response to my bot's message, but it's all happening in DMs. How can I complete this task with Discord.js (13.x)?

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents });
const config = require('./config.json');
const privateMessage = require('./private-message');
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');

    privateMessage(client, '!match', 'hello please enter your birthday as this following format day/month ')

})


client.login(config.token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a collector for that. There is a easy guide on the discord.js website.

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html